# Why is my Slick2D spritesheet animation cut off when it loops?

Tags: java, animation, slick

I am loading a SpriteSheet with Slick2D and using the Animation function in the render method to display it.
The spritesheet loads perfectly, but when the animation loops, it does so moved down a few pixels and cut in half.

It should always look like this:

[image: correctly rendered animation]

But instead does this:

[image: moved-down and cut-off animation]

Here's my code. It's smalle because it's only a test.

```
package finalProject;

import org.newdawn.slick.*;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.*;

public class Dialogue extends BasicGameState {

    private SpriteSheet SSTommy;
    private Animation ATommy;
    Music playMusic;

    public void enter(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException {
        playMusic = new Music("C:/OOP Resources/Bill Blaster.ogg");
        playMusic.play();
        playMusic.loop();
    }

    public Dialogue(int state) {
    }

    public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException {
        SSTommy = new SpriteSheet("C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/Etc/Tommy_SS.png", 41, 87);
        ATommy = new Animation(SSTommy, 150);
        ATommy.setPingPong(true);
    }

    public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
        g.drawString("This is the Play State", 100, 100);
        ATommy.draw(200, 200);
    }

    public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta) throws SlickException {
        ATommy.update(delta);
    }

    public void leave(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg) {
        playMusic.stop();
    }

    public int getID() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I tried other SpriteSheets but it keeps doing the same. I think this is releated to the render method, but I don't know what's doing it.

Comment: From the documentary of Slick2D update() method, there is an entry: update(long delta) 
          Update the animation, note that this will have odd effects if auto update is also turned on - so, check if autoUpdate of the Animation is false and try it again. Maybe this does the trick.

Comment: Sorry, I used `ATommy.setAutoUpdate(false);` and it wouldn't work. Any other suggests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you passing a sprite-sheet object to the animation, That would seem like your problem

try:

```
SpriteSheet spriteSheet;
Image player;
Animation aTommy;

public void init(){
    spriteSheet = new SpriteSheet("imgs/spriteSheet.png", sheetWidth, sheetHeight);

    player = spriteSheet.getSprite(_x, _y);
    aTommy = new Animation(player, 150);
}
```

Now if you want to actually create an animation:

```
SpriteSheet spriteSheet;
Image[4] player;
int[4] times = {150, 150, 150, 150};
Animation aTommy;

public void init(){
    spriteSheet = new SpriteSheet("imgs/spriteSheet.png", sheetWidth, sheetHeight);
    for(int i = 0; i < player.length; i++){
         player[i] = spriteSheet.getSprite(_x+i /*This is only possible if the animation frames in the spritesheet are beside eachother*/, _y);
    }
    aTommy = new Animation(player, times);
}
```

Comment: You're very welcome!